# In AEM/CQ5 , URL redirection using /etc/map not working

Tags: aem

I have a use case to redirect /content/project/en/test/events to /content/project/en/test page as internal redirection of page properties is not working .

I used following values under /etc/map/http folder :

sling:match as (.+)/en/test/(.+)$

sling:internalRedirect as (.+)/en/test.html

Still my required redirection is not working .

Please let me know correct configuration for the same .

Thanks&Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sling:internalRedirect` is the target to which user is taken so you should use in it the match from the `sling:match`

use: `sling:internalRedirect` as `$1/en/test.html`

btw. there's a useful article about mappings here: https://www.cognifide.com/our-blogs/cq/multidomain-cq-mappings-and-apache-configuration/

EDIT:
a simple config like this will work (redirect from home.html to page1.html):

[image]

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your reply.  I also followed same doc    .  I now tried new value of sling:internalRedirect , it is still not working .                                                 What value shall I add for sling:match    . I have tried all combinations , still it not works

Comment: I'd first make sure it works without any matches. sth like:

sling:match = .*/content/project/en/test/events.html$
sling:internalRedirect = /content/project/en/test.html

see whether your mapping works.

maybe the structure is the problem -> /etc/map/http/localhost_any - with your data already and resourceType sling:mapping

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html#mapping-entry-specification

Comment: Very appreciative for your help .  I followed same information and did same changes , still either it is not working or anchor gets broken . Anything you suggest I may be missing .

Comment: 1. do you save your session in crx/de ?
2. you're sure you got proper jcr:primaryType ?!
3. just copy 1 to 1 what's on screen-shot and it should work (save.)
4. paste your best try as screenshot - you're surely missing some minor thing like a typo or sth ?

Comment: 1. yes i am making change in crxde and save it .  2. yes I have .  3.) yeah I followed everything . I am using 7502 port , it should not create issue , correct ??  Not sure how it's not working at my end

Comment: As I implied earlier - place a screenshot of your config from crx/de in the original post.

Comment: Hi , Thanks a lot for your help . Your changes are working , but one thing is missing which is confusing me  . Actually what I see is on clicking to the page which should be redirecting to new page , it is serving content of new page , but url in browser is not changing .          How can I fix as browser url should also point to redirected page .

Comment: That's what an internal redirect is for!! - serve content inplace url-wise.  if you want just to redirect use sendRedirect in your jsp `<%response.sendRedirect("some-path");%>`